# Creating a Spherical Sector in Runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, polar-coordinates

I was trying to make spherical sectors in Unity3d from given phi and theta angles at runtime. I wrote a script to create this, but when it runs there is nothing shown. I know the math behind the coordinates calculation but have just started in this mesh generation. I think the issue might be in creating the triangles. Any ideas?
The Code is attached. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sector
{
Mesh mesh;
int resolution;
float radius;
int ThetaLim1;
int ThetaLim2;
int PhiLim1;
int PhiLim2;

private float DegreetoRadians(float Degrees)
{
    float rads = Degrees * (Mathf.PI / 180);
    return rads;
}

public Sector(Mesh mesh ,int ThetaLim1, int ThetaLim2, int PhiLim1, int PhiLim2, int resolution, float radius)
{
    this.mesh = mesh;
    this.resolution = resolution;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.ThetaLim1 = ThetaLim1 > ThetaLim2 ? ThetaLim1 : ThetaLim2;
    this.ThetaLim2 = ThetaLim2 < ThetaLim1 ? ThetaLim2 : ThetaLim1;
    this.PhiLim1 = PhiLim1 > PhiLim2 ? PhiLim1 : PhiLim2;
    this.PhiLim2 = PhiLim2 < PhiLim1 ? PhiLim2 : PhiLim1;
}

public void ConstructMesh()
{
    UnityEngine.Vector3[] vertices = new UnityEngine.Vector3[((ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution) * ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution)];
    int a = vertices.Length;
    int[] triangles = new int[(int)((Mathf.Sqrt(a) - 1) * (Mathf.Sqrt(a) - 1) * 6)];
    int TriIndex = 0;

    for (float theta = ThetaLim2; theta <= ThetaLim1; theta += 1/resolution)
    {
        for (float phi = PhiLim2; phi <= PhiLim1; phi += 1 / resolution)
        {
            int i = (int)(phi * theta * resolution);
            float x = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            float z = radius * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(theta));
            vertices[i] = new UnityEngine.Vector3(x, y, z);

            if (theta != resolution - 1 && phi != resolution - 1)
            {
                triangles[TriIndex] = i;
                triangles[TriIndex + 1] = i + ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution) + 1;
                triangles[TriIndex + 2] = i + ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution);

                triangles[TriIndex + 3] = i;
                triangles[TriIndex + 4] = i + 1;
                triangles[TriIndex + 5] = i + ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution) + 1;
                TriIndex += 6;

            }
        }
    }

    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}
}
```

[EDIT]
So, I did some digging again and edited my code. Now I'm sure that even the triangles generated are correct but now, I am getting an Error when I run the script, Index was out of bounds of the array at the 2d array in the loop. I checked by adding the indices of the array to my debug loop and it does not even go to the outer loop. I have no idea what is going wrong. I seem to have done everything right. Anyway the updated code is as below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sector
{
Mesh mesh;
int resolution;
float radius;
int ThetaLim1;
int ThetaLim2;
int PhiLim1;
int PhiLim2;

private float DegreetoRadians(float Degrees)
{
    float rads = Degrees * (Mathf.PI / 180);
    return rads;
}

public Sector(Mesh mesh ,int ThetaLim1, int ThetaLim2, int PhiLim1, int PhiLim2, int resolution, float radius)
{
    this.mesh = mesh;
    this.resolution = resolution;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.ThetaLim1 = ThetaLim1 > ThetaLim2 ? ThetaLim1 : ThetaLim2;
    this.ThetaLim2 = ThetaLim2 < ThetaLim1 ? ThetaLim2 : ThetaLim1;
    this.PhiLim1 = PhiLim1 > PhiLim2 ? PhiLim1 : PhiLim2;
    this.PhiLim2 = PhiLim2 < PhiLim1 ? PhiLim2 : PhiLim1;
}

public void ConstructMesh()
{
    int[,] VertexTell = new int[(ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim1) * resolution, (PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution];
    UnityEngine.Vector3[] vertices = new UnityEngine.Vector3[((ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution) * ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution)];
    int a = vertices.Length;
    int[] triangles = new int[(int)((Mathf.Sqrt(a) - 1) * (Mathf.Sqrt(a) - 1) * 6)];
    int TriIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int ThetaIndex = 0;
    int PhiIndex = 0;
    int MaxPhi = 0;

    for (float theta = ThetaLim2; theta < ThetaLim1; theta += 1/resolution)
    {
        for (float phi = PhiLim2; phi < PhiLim1; phi += 1 / resolution)
        {
            float x = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            float z = radius * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(theta));
            vertices[i] = new UnityEngine.Vector3(x, y, z);
            VertexTell[ThetaIndex, PhiIndex] = i;
            PhiIndex++;
            i++;
        }
        ThetaIndex++;
        MaxPhi = PhiIndex;
        PhiIndex = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ThetaIndex; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < MaxPhi; k++)
        {
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k + 1];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k + 1];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k + 1];
            TriIndex += 6;
        }
    }

    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}
}
```

[RE-EDIT]
So, I worked on it further and got rid of all the errors. Now I'm on to the best part, "No Errors but Nothing's working still". New Code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.VirtualTexturing;

public class Sector
{
Mesh mesh;
int resolution;
float radius;
int ThetaLim1;
int ThetaLim2;
int PhiLim1;
int PhiLim2;

private float DegreetoRadians(float Degrees)
{
    float rads = Degrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    return rads;
}

public Sector(Mesh mesh ,int ThetaLim1, int ThetaLim2, int PhiLim1, int PhiLim2, int resolution, float radius)
{
    this.mesh = mesh;
    this.resolution = resolution;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.ThetaLim1 = ThetaLim1 > ThetaLim2 ? ThetaLim1 : ThetaLim2;
    this.ThetaLim2 = ThetaLim2 < ThetaLim1 ? ThetaLim2 : ThetaLim1;
    this.PhiLim1 = PhiLim1 > PhiLim2 ? PhiLim1 : PhiLim2;
    this.PhiLim2 = PhiLim2 < PhiLim1 ? PhiLim2 : PhiLim1;
}

public void ConstructMesh()
{
    int index1 = (ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution;
    int index2 = (PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution;
    Debug.Log("INDEX OF THETA " + index1 + " INDEX OF PHI " + index2);
    int[,] VertexTell = new int[(ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution, (PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution];
    Debug.Log(VertexTell.Length);
    UnityEngine.Vector3[] vertices = new UnityEngine.Vector3[((ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution) * ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution)];
    UnityEngine.Vector3[] normals = new UnityEngine.Vector3[vertices.Length];
    int[] triangles = new int[((ThetaLim1 - ThetaLim2) * resolution - 1) * ((PhiLim1 - PhiLim2) * resolution - 1) * 6];
    int TriIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;

    float res = resolution * 1.0f;

    for (int j = 0; j < index1; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < index2; k++)
        {
            float theta = ThetaLim2 + (j /res);
            float phi = PhiLim2 + (k /res);
            float x = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            float y = radius * Mathf.Cos(DegreetoRadians(theta));
            float z = radius * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(theta)) * Mathf.Sin(DegreetoRadians(phi));
            vertices[i] = new UnityEngine.Vector3(x, y, z);
            normals[i] = new UnityEngine.Vector3(Mathf.Pow(0 - x, 2) / Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(y, 2) + Mathf.Pow(z, 2)), Mathf.Pow(0 - y, 2) / Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(y, 2) + Mathf.Pow(z, 2)), Mathf.Pow(0 - z, 2) / Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(y, 2) + Mathf.Pow(z, 2)));
            VertexTell[j, k] = i;
            i++;
            // Now how the hell should I calculate normals?
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < index1 - 1 ; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < index2 - 1; k++)
        {
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k + 1];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j, k + 1];
            triangles[TriIndex] = VertexTell[j + 1, k + 1];
            TriIndex += 6;
        }
    }

    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

}
}
```

Comment: some general suggestions: Check that the normals/triangle directions are not inverted. Try exporting the mesh and open in some third party tool so you can verify the mesh construction.

Comment: I actually followed a little off a youtube tutorial where he procedurally generated spheres for making planets, he used the same function for calculating the normals, it is unity's own normals calculating function. Plus I only have ever worked on unity before.